# Magento 2 - Duplicate Cron jobs in cron_schedule table

Tags: magento2, cron, duplicate, schedule

I have Magento 2 setup of version 2.2.2.

I have set the cronjobs as per [guidelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwLQh.jpg).

When I check the `cron_schedule` table I can see multiple duplicate cronjobs entries.
`created_at` is the same for the same `job_code` and `scheduled_at` time is set with a difference of 1 minute as per the below image.

[image]

I haven't changed any default configurations in `configuration -> Advance -> System -> Cron (Scheduled Tasks)`.

Comment: I think you set 1-minute interval cron. Right?

Comment: you are talking in crontab?

Comment: Yes @RizwanKhan

Comment: Yes it is 1 miniute interval cron [* * * * *]

Comment: That's why `scheduled_at` time is set with a difference of 1 minutes.

Comment: Yes, but question is .. why there is 20 entry for same job_code at a time..

Comment: It is Magento's default functionality. Do not worry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100788/discussion-between-rizwan-khan-and-dhaduk-mitesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `configuration -> Advance -> System -> Cron (Scheduled Tasks) -> Cron configuration options for group: default`.

Set `Schedule Ahead for` field as `1`.

Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

And then check it.